# Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Date[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  consultar ( opcion: string, articulo: Articulo ): Observable<Date[]> {
    return this.http.get<Date[]>( this.rootUrl + "consultar?opcion=" + opcion, articulo );
  }
```

PROBLEM: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Date[]>'.
Type 'ArrayBuffer' is missing the following properties from type 'Date[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter in get should be options, but you are probably passing it data.

[Angular docs - get method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get)

> Constructs a GET request that interprets the body as an ArrayBuffer and returns the response in an ArrayBuffer.

[image: Get Method Parameters]

Answer (score 4):

Since the accepted Suggested edit queue is full right now - 2022-06-25 - I decided to write this answer which contains more details and example to elaborate and illuminate the problem:

## Elaborating the problem

I had an interface:

```
export interface Media {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  medium: string;
  category: string | null;
  year: string | null;
  watchedOn: string | null;
  isFavorite: boolean | null;
}
```

And a service layer which was responsible to perform http calls:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MediaService {
  private readonly baseUrl: string;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.baseUrl = environment.baseUrl.concat('/medias');
  }

  get(filters: Partial<Media>): Observable<Media[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<Media[]>(this.baseUrl, {
        params: { ...filters },
      })
      .pipe(
        map((media) => {
          // TODO: Do required normalization
          return media;
        }),
      );
  }
}
```

When we are doing something like this Angular think we wanna use this overload:

```
get(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    context?: HttpContext;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: 'arraybuffer';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<ArrayBuffer>;
```

While we do not.

## Solution

The problem rises from those `| null` which we have in our interface. We need to somehow guarantee that we won't pass `null` value to the http param. `JSON` can just do that, So in the service layer I change the `get` method just like this:

```
get(filters: Partial<Media>): Observable<Media[]> {
  // All the magic happens in these two line:
  const illuminateNils = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filters));
  const params = new HttpParams({
    fromObject: illuminateNils,
  });

  return this.httpClient
    .get<Media[]>(this.baseUrl, {
      params,
    })
    .pipe(
      map((media) => {
        // TODO: Do required normalization
        return media;
      }),
    );
}
```

And now Typescript is not hysterical. And our code is more secure and understandable thanks to picky Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue myself when trying to use response headers in a subsequent request myself.

```
return this.http.post(url, myObject, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(mergeMap((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
  const url = res.headers.get('Location');
  return this.http.get<MyObject>(url!);
}));
```

The solution for me was to add a ! after the url. Not sure why a nullable string caused Typescript to think my observable was returning an ArrayBuffer.